# Object convert to float with spacing and minus calculation symbol python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

```
    Time       Floating P/L    
2   2019.09.30  -16.60  
3   2019.10.01  -4.40   
4   2019.10.02  -1 162.04   
5   2019.10.03  -82.88
```

I have a database the column Floating P/L is object that I need to convert it to float. I tried google, this default way is used:

```
df['Floating P/L'] = df['Floating P/L'].replace('[^\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
```

However, after doing this, the minus symbol is deleted

```
2        16.60
3         4.40
4      1162.04
5        82.88
```

I am wondering how can I keep the minus symbol, I assume others may have the same problem, so I post it here

Comment: Well, `[^\d.]` removes the minus sign as well. Try `[^-\d.]`.

Comment: Why not replace the spaces instead of number's ``df['Floating P/L'].str.replace("\s", "").astype(float)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use

```
df['Floating P/L'] = df['Floating P/L'].replace('[^-\d.]', '', regex=True).astype(float)
#                                                 ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove all whitespaces (`\s`) and then convert to `float` that is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Floating':['-16.60','-4.40','-1 162.04','-82.88']})
df['Floating'] = df['Floating'].replace('\s', '', regex=True).astype(float)
print(df)
print(df['Floating'].dtype)
```

Output:

```
   Floating
0    -16.60
1     -4.40
2  -1162.04
3    -82.88
float64
```